# SessionFactory XML configuration works, but not Java configuration. Why?

Tags: spring-java-config

In a Spring XML configuration, I have the followings:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   ....
</bean>
```

and in a Java class, I have
        @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
without a setter. That works.
Now, I change the sessionFactory to a Java configuration as the followings.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:jdbc.properties" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    lsfb.addAnnotatedClasses(...);
            lsfb.setProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return lsfb.buildSessionFactory();
    }
  // ...
}
```

And I get an error "could not autowire field". Adding a setter doesn't help. Why the sessionFactory can't get autowired with a Java configuration?

BTW, I can work around this problem by having a Java configuration for the DAO as well.

Comment: do you use spring data jpa? Maybe @EnableJpaRepositories("com..") above configuration could help? Have you checked if sessionFactory() method is called during application startup? Maybe you did not wire spring with class which implements WebApplicationInitializer?

Comment: The application was built before Spring Data inception. The persistence configuration is started in the getRootConfigClasses() method of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no `@ComponentScan` annotation on your `@Configuration` class, so probably the problem is in how you import this configuration. Please ensure that all particular beans live in the same context or at least that `PersistenceConfig` is parent to the context in which you are autowiring SessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

I have added the @ComponentScan annotation and it doesn't solve the problem. The annotation tells Spring to look for any @Components to configure as beans. This problem seems to me is that during the process of creating a bean with @Component, it can't find a bean configured in my Java configuration file which is started in WebAppInitializer.